# Removing Quote From Field For Filename Using AWK

Tags: awk

I've been playing around with this for an hour trying to work out how to embed the removal of quotes from a specific field using AWK.

Basically, the file encapsulates text in quotes, but I want to use the second field to name the file and split them based on the first field.

```
ID,Name,Value1,Value2,Value3
1,"AAA","DEF",1,2
1,"AAA","GGG",7,9
2,"BBB","DEF",1,2
2,"BBB","DEF",9,0
3,"CCC","AAA",1,1
```

What I want to get out are three files, all with the header row named:

```
AAA [1].csv
BBB [2].csv
CCC [3].csv
```

I have got it all working, except for the fact that I can't for the life of me work out how to remove the quotes around the filename!!

So, this command does everything (except the file is named with quotes around $2, but I need to do some kind of transformation on $2 before it goes into evname.  In the actual file, I want to keep the encapsulating quotes.

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{h=$0;next}!($1 in files){evname=$2" ["$1"].csv";files[$1]=1;print h>evname}{print > evname}' DataExtract.csv
```

I've tried to push a gsub into this, but I'm struggling to work out exactly how this should look.

This is I think as close as I have got, but it is just calling everything "2" for $2, I'm not sure if this means I need to do an escape of $2 somehow in the gsub, but trying that doesn't seem to be working, so I'm at a loss as to what I'm doing wrong.

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{h=$0;next}!($1 in files){evname=gsub(""\","", $2)" - Event ID ["$1"].csv";files[$1]=1;print h>evname}{print > evname}' DataExtract.csv
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

Gannon

Comment: It is not very clear how your output should look like. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand what you are attempting correctly, then

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{h=$0;next}!($1 in files){gsub(/"/, "", $2); evname=$2" ["$1"].csv";files[$1]=1;print h>evname}{print > evname}' DataExtract.csv
```

should work. That is

```
NR == 1 {
  h = $0;
  next
}
!($1 in files) {
  stub = $2                     # <-- this is the new bit: make a working copy
                                # of $2 (so that $2 is unchanged and the line
                                # is not rebuilt with changes for printing),
  gsub(/"/, "", stub)           # remove the quotes from it, and
  evname = stub " [" $1 "].csv" # use it to assemble the filename.
  files[$1] = 1;
  print h > evname
}
{
  print > evname
}
```

You can, of course, use

```
evname = stub " - Event ID [" $1 "].csv"
```

or any other format after the substitution (this one seems to be what you tried to get in your second code snippet).

The `gsub` function returns the number of substitutions made, not the result of the substitutions; that is why `evname=gsub(""\","", $2)" - Event ID ["$1"].csv"` does not work.

Comment: Ah, I thought the gsub was somehow ignoring the fact that I wanted $2 and was just giving me the 2, didn't think it was because there were two subsititutions.

This is very close to what I need ... the only problem is then that the contents of the files have the encapsulation removed from $2 and the first line of values (after the printing of h) has all commas removed as well.  Data lines 2-n (that is file lines 3-n) look correct (encapsulated and comma delimited).

Is there a way to only remove the quotes for use in the filename, not for the printing to the relevant files?

Comment: `tmp = $2; gsub(/"/, "", tmp); evname = tmp " - Event ID [" $2 "].csv"` -- just make a copy of `$2` and work with that. Actually, let me change that in the answer; it's really a bug.

Comment: [slaps forehead!]

That makes so much sense - thanks Wintermute!!

You're right, that is exactly what I was trying to achieve (sorry the second statement was a little different, I was trying to simplify to work out the issue, but you spotted both - very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Things are always clearer with a little white space:

```
awk -F, '
    NR==1 { hdr=$0; next }
    !seen[$1]++ {
        evname = $2
        gsub(/"/,"",evname)
        outfile = evname " [" $1 "].csv"
        print hdr > outfile
    }
    { print > outfile }
' DataExtract.csv
```

Aside: It's pretty unusual for someone to WANT to create files with spaces in their names given the complexity that introduces in any later scripts you write to process them. You sure you want to do that?

P.S. here's the gawk version as suggested by @JID below

```
awk -F, '
    NR==1 { hdr=$0; next }
    !seen[$1]++ {
        outfile = gensub(/"/,"","g",$2) " [" $1 "].csv"
        print hdr > outfile
    }
    { print > outfile }
' DataExtract.csv
```

Comment: Could you not just use gensub instead of creating a new variable ?

Comment: Yes but that'd make it gawk-specific and I usually don't do that just for the sake of 1 variable when the portable awk is so trivial.

Comment: Okay :). it was just from OP's original code it looked like they were trying to use gsub as though it was gensub.Probably is better to do it this way though actually :)

Comment: I added a gawk version at the end, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the gsub before you make the assignment:

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{h=$0;next}
    !($1 in files){
    gsub("\"","",$2);  # Add this line
    evname=$2" ["$1"].csv";files[$1]=1;print...
```